# Linking un-named workbook to variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that will copy and paste information form one workbook into another workbook in excel 2010. The workbook that the data is in is the same workbook as the macro. I have made VBA create a new workbook to paste the data in. How do I assign the new workbook that VBA has just created to a variable.

Thanks For Any Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned exactly how you create the workbook, but you can set a reference to the new `Workbook` object in the same statement that creates it.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddWorkbook()

    Dim oWb As Workbook

    Set oWb = Workbooks.Add

    'Do something with the new workbook
    Debug.Print oWb.FullName

    Set oWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am adding the workbook using 'Workbooks.Add' and the workbook will be sent out this means i cannot use a name because it will not be the same on all computers.

Comment: @Hannah When you call `Set oWb = Workbooks.Add` you have a reference to the new workbook in variable `oWB` in your VBA code - isn't that what you want? You can get the local name by the property `oWB.Name`.

Comment: yes thank you. it was really winding me up because i got it working with a named sheet and then i had to change it and it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

try seeing names of all workbooks by iterating over Workbooks. I think the name of newly created workbook will "Workbook1" until there is already no other unnamed workbook. So basically newly created workbook is still not unnamed.