# VBA trying to specify a newly created workbook rather than activeworkbook (to paste some data into the new one)

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some code that copies some data, then I want it to create a new workbook and paste the copied data into the new workbook. At the moment the code uses `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial` etc which is fine if the newly created workbook is the active sheet but if it isnt that obviously doesn't work. here's the entire sub (with some `stop` markers as i've been debugging it):

```
Sub ExportToCSV()
Dim ws As Worksheet, xFolder As String, xName As String
Dim InitialFoldr$

InitialFoldr$ = "L:\107xxx\1077898 A34 Oxford junctions 1718\200 M & A"

MsgBox ("Choose where to save the Paramics demands")
xFolder = GetFolder(InitialFoldr$)

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*PDMND" Then
        xName = ws.Name
        ws.Range("BJ4:CK82").Copy
        'Stop
        With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            .Workbooks.Add
            .Visible = True
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Stop
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFolder + "\" + xName + ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    'Stop
Next
End Sub
```

After the `with` loop to create the new workbook, i want to make a variable that refers to the new workbook and then i can use the variable to paste the data in the right place - or something akin to this - to replace the `ActiveSheet.Paste` bit. How do I accomplish this?

Edit: I have used the information in the similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247641/linking-un-named-workbook-to-variable-in-vba) so my code now looks like this:

```
xFolder = GetFolder(InitialFoldr$)

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*PDMND" Then
        xName = ws.Name
    ws.Range("BJ4:CK82").Copy

    Set oWb = Workbooks.Add

            oWb.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Stop
```

But now Excel crashes without fail after I select the save folder. Is there an obvious reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking un-named workbook to variable in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247641/linking-un-named-workbook-to-variable-in-vba)

Comment: `dim wbtemp as workbook`  and `set  wbtemp = .Workbooks.Add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new workbook, save the workbook object so you can reference it later... like this:

Before you start your loop add:

```
    Dim wbNew as Workbook
```

Then inside your loop...

```
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set wbNew = .Workbooks.Add
        .Visible = True
    End With
    wbNew.WorkSheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Yes! thanks. but now when it pastes, it pastes the formats too and brings up a dialog box that says "The range you are pasting contains formulas that cannot be pasted into this instance of Excel; however, the formulas will be pasted as values..." even though I've got the line that does the pasting specifying as values. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Did you also update the line that saves to use `oWb` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Yes i did. Its not actually a problem because i'm saving as .csv files and the formats don't save anyway, but its a bit weird.